# Why is the marquee element not working on chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used a `marquee` element inside of a `div` element.

It looks fine in Internet Explorer but in Chrome the text goes beyond `div`.

However, in another page on the same site I did a marquee too and it works on Chrome.

What to do?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee - no longer supported in newer versions of chrome.

Comment: marquee is something you dont want to use nowadays, jquery can slide elements a lot better

Comment: if i whant marquee how can be fix?

Comment: [`marquee`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee) has been burnitated just like [`blink`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/blink).

Comment: Without seeing your attempts how can we possibly say what is, or might be, wrong?

Comment: so how can it works on other page that i did and not in the page i am doing now?

Comment: Let's bring back scrolling blinking status bar text. The trifecta of late-90's painful web annoyances.

Comment: The site will not let me send the code of the page utill i have 10 questions

Comment: Check out http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6re0dtr4/
  the code with the proublem

Comment: @user3650666: I recommend spending some time to learn jsFiddle. The JS and CSS section should not contain HTML for example.

Answer (score 2):

The `<marquee>` element is no longer supported in Chrome.

It's deprecated, you should not use it: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee

Answer (score 2):

[HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0) classifies `marquee` as a [non-conforming feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features):

> The [`marquee`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0) element is a presentational element that animates
>   content. CSS transitions and animations are a more appropriate
>   mechanism. [[CSSANIMATIONS]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsCSSANIMATIONS) [[CSSTRANSITIONS]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsCSSTRANSITIONS)

To achieve that functionality, you could use those CSS modules:

- [CSS Animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/)
- [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)
- [CSS Marquee Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/).